# Pandas DataFrame merging with aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Let's create 2 dataframes, df1 and df2:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"], ["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1"], [10, 10, 20, 20, 30], [1, 5, 6, 3, 4]]).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["B", "B", "C", "F"], ["b1", "b3", "c1", "f2"], [30, 30, 40, 40], [8, 3, 5, 2]]).T
df1.columns = df2.columns = ["label1", "label2", "total", "count"]
```

Please notice, "total" must be the same for each "label1"

I need to merge theses 2 dataframes following these rules :

- All "count" with same "label2" are simply added. ex: in df1, b1=6, in df2, b1=8, when merged, b1=14
- "total" with same "label1" are added (and must be the same for each "label1"). ex: in df1, all B=20, in df2, all B=30, when merged, all B=50

In df3, this is what I'm trying to get:

[image]

I think I should maybe use pandas.DataFrame.merge, 1 or 2 times, but I don't even understand how to aggregate data. Any clue is appreciated.

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: Where `(F, f1)` come from?

Comment: @Either : True :) if you really want a question : "How would I do that?"

Comment: yeah lack of attempt makes it a bad question still

Comment: @Corralien : These are some kind of ID from a database and categories attached to these IDs. There are intersections in quantities counted, so a "real" sum is  pre-computed and duplicated in "label1"

Comment: @Cyrille. What I mean it's `(F, f1)` is not in `df1` and `df2`. Check the output of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71038380/15239951)

Comment: @Corralien : oh, you are right, it's a typo. Good catch.

Comment: @Corralien : well... all answers are good and interesting. I will arbitrarily accept yours then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge first then aggregate:

```
cols = ['label1', 'label2']
prefix = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]

out = df1.merge(df2, on=cols, how='outer').set_index(cols) \
         .groupby(by=prefix, sort=False, axis=1).sum().reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
  label1 label2  total  count
0      A     a1     10      1
1      A     a2     10      5
2      B     b1     50     14
3      B     b2     20      3
4      C     c1     70      9
5      B     b3     30      3
6      F     f2     40      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"], ["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1"], [10, 10, 20, 20, 30], [1, 5, 6, 3, 4]]).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["B", "B", "C", "F"], ["b1", "b3", "c1", "f2"], [30, 30, 40, 40], [8, 3, 5, 2]]).T
df1.columns = df2.columns = ["label1", "label2", "total", "count"]

df_both = df1.assign(df=1).append(df2.assign(df=2))

df_lable1 = df_both.drop_duplicates(['label1', 'df']).groupby('label1')['total'].sum().reset_index()
df_lable2 = df_both.groupby('label2')['count'].sum().reset_index()

df3 = df_both[['label1', 'label2']].drop_duplicates(["label1", "label2"]).sort_values(["label1", "label2"])

df3 = df3.merge(df_lable1, on=['label1'], how='left')
df3 = df3.merge(df_lable2, on=['label2'], how='left')

#   label1 label2 total count
# 0      A     a1    10     1
# 1      A     a2    10     5
# 2      B     b1    50    14
# 3      B     b2    50     3
# 4      B     b3    50     3
# 5      C     c1    70     9
# 6      F     f2    40     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df3 = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2])
    .pipe(lambda x: (x.assign(total=x['label1'].map(x.groupby('label1')['total'].unique().apply(sum))))
    .groupby(['label1', 'label2'])
    .agg(total=('total', 'first'), count=('count', 'sum'))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
  label1 label2  total  count
0      A     a1     10      1
1      A     a2     10      5
2      B     b1     50     14
3      B     b2     50      3
4      B     b3     50      3
5      C     c1     70      9
6      F     f2     40      2
```